# Drawing A2xA2 Dynkin diagram with dynkin-diagrams

Tags: diagrams

This is a follow up question: How do I draw it exactly as in the blackboard picture I provide, that is with ellipses around the nodes and for the bottom one with the connections to the rightmost node straight not curved.

I posted it as a comment first but I am not sure people notice when comments are added. Thanks a lot.

Edit: here is minimal working example

```
\documentclass[12pt]{amsbook}

\usepackage{dynkin-diagrams}

\begin{document}
 
 Question: how do I produced a diagram which only keeps the square in this diagram 
 \dynkin[fold] A{*****}? I.e. a Satake-Tits diagram of type A2xA2 but I do not want to have just \dynkin A2 \dynkin A2 but have the nodes paired up. 

\end{document}
```

---

I am using the excellent package Dynkin-diagram .sty
and drawing the diagrams for the non-split version of the Freudenthal-Tits magic square.
I managed to draw all but one of them. In picture below the bottom one
can easily be drawn with

`\dynkin[fold] A{*****}`

My question is how do I draw the top one? Thanks a lot

[image]

Addition: Benjamin Kindly offered to include FTMS non-split into his package. The others I managed to draw, here the output as well as latex code which produces it

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{amsbook}
\usepackage[dvipsnames,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{dynkin-diagrams}


\begin{document}
 
\begin{center}
\Large
\begin{tabular}{| c | c | c | c | c |}\hline
\cellcolor{lightgray!90} $\mathbb{A}\setminus \mathbb{B}$ &  \cellcolor{lightgray!90} $\mathbb{K}$  & \cellcolor{lightgray!90} $\mathbb{L}$   & \cellcolor{lightgray!90} $\mathbb{H}$ & \cellcolor{lightgray!90} $\mathbb{O}$  \\ \hline
\cellcolor{lightgray!90} $\mathbb{K}$ &  \cellcolor{BurntOrange!80} \dynkin A1  & \cellcolor{BurntOrange!80}  \dynkin A{*o}   & \cellcolor{BurntOrange!80} \dynkin C{o*o} & \cellcolor{BurntOrange!80} \dynkin F{*ooo}  \\ \hline
\cellcolor{lightgray!90} $\mathbb{L}$ &  \cellcolor{SeaGreen} \dynkin A{**}  & \cellcolor{SeaGreen} \begin{dynkinDiagram}[name=upper]A2
\node (current) at ($(upper root 1)+(0,-.35cm)$) {};
\dynkin[at=(current),name=lower]A2
\begin{pgfonlayer}{Dynkin behind}
\foreach \i in {1,2}{%
\draw[/Dynkin diagram/fold style] ($(upper root \i)$) -- ($(lower root \i)$);}
\end{pgfonlayer}
\end{dynkinDiagram}& \cellcolor{SeaGreen} \dynkin A{*ooo*} & \cellcolor{SeaGreen} \dynkin E{*oooo*}\\ \hline
\cellcolor{lightgray!90} $\mathbb{H}$  &  \cellcolor{RoyalBlue!50} \dynkin C{***}  & \cellcolor{RoyalBlue!50} \dynkin[fold] A{*****} & \cellcolor{RoyalBlue!50} \dynkin D{*oo*o*} & \cellcolor{RoyalBlue!50} \dynkin E{*oooo**}\\ \hline
\cellcolor{lightgray!90} $\mathbb{O}$ &  \cellcolor{OrangeRed!70} \dynkin F{****}  &  \cellcolor{OrangeRed!70} \begin{dynkinDiagram}[mark=o]E{II} \dynkinRootMark{*}1
\dynkinRootMark{*}3 \dynkinRootMark{*}5 \dynkinRootMark{*}6 \dynkinRootMark{*}2 \dynkinRootMark{*}4 \end{dynkinDiagram}

& \cellcolor{OrangeRed!70} \dynkin[backwards] E{*o**oo*o} & \cellcolor{Red} ${\color{white} \dynkin E{*oooo***}}$\\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Also here are the diagrams as made in Keynote, they are drawn to emphasize the residual property, namely taking a point residue (covering a dot if you are unfamiliar with buildings language) in a picture yields the one above when going from row 4 to 3, row 3 to 2 (row 2 to 1 is different and uses folding)

[image]

Comment: would you like to share your code

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. When you post a question, please provide a ["Minimal Working Example" (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that starts with `\documentclass`, includes all relevant `\usepackage` commands, ends with `\end{document}` and compiles without errors, even if it does not produce your desired output.

Comment: Thanks I have added the minimal working example. I know this can probably be achieved by meticulously composing diagrams and drawing arrows but I wondered if there is a hack where I can use a predefined diagram such as the one I draw and instruct to omit some vertices and edges.

Comment: Would you like to draw the ellipses in your diagrams above? That might also not be so difficult.

Comment: Where did you find those two diagrams you provided? I might try to put the whole non-split Freudenthal-Tits classification into the package documentation if I knew what diagrams to draw.

Comment: Made in keynote, I'll add the picture in my question, thanks very much.

Comment: I would also like to know now how to draw the ellipses in the diagrams and also how in e.g. the second row second column one can draw the arms to the rightmost node straight instead of curved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Connecting diagrams is described in §28 of the Dynkin Diagrams [Package documentation](https://mirrors.rit.edu/CTAN/graphics/pgf/contrib/dynkin-diagrams/dynkin-diagrams.pdf).

[image]

You can adjust the vertical space between `upper` and `lower` by changing the `-.3cm` in the code below:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{amsbook}

\usepackage{dynkin-diagrams}

\begin{document}

Is this:
\begin{dynkinDiagram}[name=upper]A2
\node (current) at ($(upper root 1)+(0,-.3cm)$) {};
\dynkin[at=(current),name=lower]A2
\begin{pgfonlayer}{Dynkin behind}
\foreach \i in {1,2}{%
\draw[/Dynkin diagram/fold style] ($(upper root \i)$) -- ($(lower root \i)$);}
\end{pgfonlayer}
\end{dynkinDiagram}
what you want?

\end{document}
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

This is not an answer, but it won't fit as a comment. Here are some very slight changes to your code which I hope make clearer how it works.

[image: The nonsplit Freudenthal-Tits magic square]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{amsbook}
\usepackage[dvipsnames,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{dynkin-diagrams}
\begin{document}
\arrayrulecolor{white}
\makeatletter
\def\rulecolor#1#{\CT@arc{#1}}
\def\CT@arc#1#2{%
  \ifdim\baselineskip=\z@\noalign\fi
  {\gdef\CT@arc@{\color#1{#2}}}}
\let\CT@arc@\relax
\rulecolor{white}
\makeatother
\begin{center}
\newcommand\clrK{\rowcolor{BurntOrange!80}}
\newcommand\clrL{\rowcolor{SeaGreen}}
\newcommand\clrH{\rowcolor{RoyalBlue!50}}
\newcommand\clrO{\rowcolor{OrangeRed!70}}
\newcommand\clrOO{\cellcolor{Red}}
\newcommand\rw[1]{\csname clr#1\endcsname\hd{#1}}
\NewDocumentCommand\hd{om}{
\cellcolor{gray!30}$\IfNoValueF{#1}{\mathbb{#1}\setminus}\mathbb{#2}$}
\tikzset{/Dynkin diagram/fold style/.style={blue!22,ultra thick}}
\let\d=\dynkin
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|}\hline
\hd[A]{B}&\hd{K}&\hd{L}&\hd{H}&\hd{O}\\ \hline
\rw{K}& \d A1  & \d A{*o} & \d C{o*o} & \d F{*ooo} \\ \hline
\rw{L}& \d A{**} & 
\begin{dynkinDiagram}[name=upper]A2
\node (current) at ($(upper root 1)+(0,-.35cm)$) {};
\d[at=(current),name=lower]A2
\begin{pgfonlayer}{Dynkin behind}
\foreach \i in {1,2}{%
\draw[/Dynkin diagram/fold style] ($(upper root \i)$) -- ($(lower root \i)$);}
\end{pgfonlayer}
\end{dynkinDiagram}& 
\d A{*ooo*} & 
\d E{*oooo*} \\ \hline
\rw{H} &
\d C{***} &
\d[fold] A{*****} &
\d D{*oo*o*} &
\d E{*oooo**}\\ \hline
\rw{O} & 
\d F{****} &
\d[o/.style = {solid,draw=black,fill=black}] E{II} & 
\d[backwards] E{*o**oo*o} & 
\clrOO \d E{*oooo***}\\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```